# Timing a user out after to many unsuccessful login attempts

Tags: php, mysql

i am creating a lockout system for my CMS page. The idea is to time out a user after 5 bad attempts within 24 hours, for 48 hours. But, if a user enters the correct password within the 24 hours, the account the time out should be removed. I am having trouble with the timing out and unlocking the user account after both a successful attempt and unsuccessful attempts.

The idea is after the failed attempts and timeout occurs, if they enter a password correctly, it cancels the time out. If they enter the password wrong again within the 24hours (after the timeout) the  previous bad attempts are ignored and it only looks the latest failed attempt after the last successful attempt.

I have created a table to store the UNSUCCESSFUL attempts. I need help with to have the code check the last 5 consecutive failed attempts > time the account out.  Then if a user puts in the right password (within 24hours) > remove timeout.

```
    $qry = "    SELECT 
                                CASE WHEN count(*) >= 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as allowed_login 
                            FROM
                                cms_user_login_attempts
                            WHERE
                                cula_date_time >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, interval 48 hour) 
                            AND 
                                cula_user_id = " . $db->SQLString($row->user_id) . "";
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to lock out a user if they enter the wrong password too many times, but if they enter the right one, you'll let them back in? Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of locking like this in the first place?

Comment: That is correct, yes. Its a specification I have to go by. I'd like to change it, but can't.

Comment: I would have thought that a security concern like this would be a very good reason to dispute the specification.

Comment: But if they are locked out how are they going to log in with the correct password?

Comment: I don't see how anyone gets "locked out" if they can pass whenever they enter the correct password.

Comment: Perhaps bring it up with your superior with the question "And what do we do if they enter the *wrong* password during that 24 hour period?"

Comment: the lockout is more of a time out error, sorry I should chose my words correctly.

Comment: Ok im not sure you really need an additional table you coudl just store the number of failed attempts, the last login (successful). When the attempts get to 5 and last login is older than 24 hours then you reject all attempts... otherwise on every successful login you reset the number of failed attempts. Nothning wrong with another table but unless you need to store a lot of additional information or need a full audit log i dont think its necessary.

Comment: The idea is after the failed attempts and timeout occurs, if they enter a password correctly, it cancels the time out. If they enter the password wrong again within the 24hours (after the timeout) the  previous bad attempts are ignored and it only looks the latest failed attempt after the last successful attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the part where you don't actually lock anyone out I'd use a different approach.

I'd add a field *last_bad_login_time* and *bad_login_attempts* to your user table. Whenever the use enters a bad password and hasn't had N attempts in timespan X increment the #attempts (watch out for overflows, haha) and update the timestamp.
If the user logs in correctly flush both fields (or just the #attempts).

Comment: Hello thanks for that, I previously had a attempts colomn, but my supervisor said he doesn't like that. All he wants it to do is look at past 5 consecutive attempts, within 24 hours, if its more than 5, time them out. If they enter a correct password after the 5 attempts within 24 hours, then let them in. He said i needed to create a sub query, just a little lost, i'm an intern with small programming experience haha.